# How to rename a default constraint on Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to rename many constraints (PK, FK, ...etc. ) that have default names which start with 'SYS' to be able to insert the same data in other DB.

I found the following script that I changed to get what I want:

```
BEGIN
    FOR cn IN (
        SELECT constraint_name 
        FROM user_constraints 
        WHERE constraint_type = 'P'
        AND table_name = 'SPECIALITE'
    )
    LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE ' || cn.table_name || ' RENAME CONSTRAINT ' || cn.constraint_name  || ' TO PK_' || 'SPECIALITE';
    END LOOP;
END;
```

This script works, but it seems a bit complicated for me, I wonder if it exists something like:

```
ALTER TABLE 'SPECIALITE' RENAME CONSTRANT (....)
```

The problem is I don't know the name of constraints, they have a default name, I know only tables where they are.

Is it possible?

Comment: I think you are out of luck. There is `alter table xyz drop|enable|disable primary key`, but the syntax is not supported for `rename`.

Comment: If you know the constraint column(s) you could drop and recreate it - if you `ALTER TABLE SPECIALITE DROP PRIMARY KEY KEEP INDEX;` then you can add a new PK without having to rebuild the index, though that will retain the old system-generated name. But if you don't - and as you're renaming many you probably don't - then you'd have to find them dynamically anyway, so what you have now would be simpler.

Comment: Why dont you use user_cons_columns which has tablename ,constraint name and other relevant info.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE SPECIALITE RENAME CONSTRAINT SYS_C002786098 TO PK_SPECIALITE` is the command.  You need to know the name of the constraint that you are renaming.  You can get the name of the constraint from `USER_CONSTRAINTS` for tables you own.  i.e. -- your script is just fine.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - not out of luck; the syntax is `alter table rename constraint ....` and it works for primary keys and for all other constraints that can be named. (`not null` constraints can't be named, but that makes sense - you can't reference a `not null` constraint.)

Comment: @AlexPoole - Since constraints can be renamed, I don't think it ever makes sense to drop and recreate a PK just to rename it. There may be foreign keys pointing to the PK and all those relationships will be lost. I didn't check but I **assume** renaming doesn't do that; besides the name, the PK must also have an internal id, and foreign keys should point to that internal id, not to the name. Dropping the PK destroys the internal id, not just the name.

Comment: @mathguy - I know you can rename constraints. I was hoping there was an `alter table xyz rename primary key to xyz_pk` command similar to `alter table xyz drop primary key`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you already know, you need to run two queries.

```
select constraint_name from user_constraints 
where table_name = <table_name> and constraint_type = 'P';
```

and with the constraint name in hand,

```
alter table <table_name> rename constraint <old_constr_name> to <new_constr_name>;
```

This will require copying the constraint name from the first query and pasting it into the second, in the proper place (`<old_constr_name>`).

If this was all, I wouldn't post an answer. But I remember something I read on AskTom some time ago - a clever way to avoid copying and pasting, using the COLUMN command in SQL*Plus. (This may also work in SQL Developer and Toad.) Something like this:

```
column constraint_name new_val c   -- Note: no semicolon - this is SQL*Plus, not SQL

select constraint_name from user_constraints 
where table_name = <table_name> and constraint_type = 'P';

alter table <table_name> rename constraint &c to <new_constr_name>;
```

If you need to change many PK constraint names, this will save some work. The constraint name returned by the SELECT query is saved in the "new_val" labeled "c" from the SQL*Plus COLUMN command, and it is used in the ALTER TABLE statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the constraint name, you can't do it directly. But you can easily generate the statement.

```
select 'ALTER TABLE ' || table_name || ' RENAME CONSTRAINT ' || constraint_name || ' TO PK_' || upper( table_name )
from user_constraints
where constraint_type = 'P'
and constraint_name like 'SYS%';
```

This select will list all tables with a constraint on its primary key that start by 'SYS'and rename it to PK_TABLE_NAME;

You just have to check if all statements looks ok for you and run them.

You also can use the generated column like this

```
select 'ALTER TABLE ' || table_name || ' RENAME CONSTRAINT ' || constraint_name || ' TO PK_' || upper( table_name )
from user_constraints
where constraint_type = 'P'
and generated = 'GENERATED NAME';
```

but you will have BIN tables and maybe other unwanted tables

Answer (score 0):

Add `user_cons_columns` view to your SQL so you can generate constraint names. Here is a quick and dirty example:

```
select 'ALTER TABLE ' || c.table_name || ' RENAME CONSTRAINT ' || c.constraint_name  || ' TO ' || substr(c.constraint_type || '_' || c.table_name || '_' || replace(wm_concat(cc.column_name), ',', '_'), 0, 30) || ';'
from user_constraints c
join user_cons_columns cc on c.table_name = cc.table_name and c.constraint_name = cc.constraint_name
where c.constraint_name like 'SYS%'
group by c.table_name, c.constraint_name, c.constraint_type;
```

This SQL generates an executable script with commands like this:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLENAME RENAME CONSTRAINT SYS_xxxxxx TO C_TABLENAME_COLUMN;
```

Please note that I'm using undocumented `wm_concat` function. If you're using Oracle >= 11g consider using `listagg` instead.